# Getting dynamically fetched selector

Tags: jquery

What I need to do is get the '.clippy' class to be my selector, just selector no events but it seems that it doesn't work

How can I get the selector from a ajax response element

If I do this `$('body').on( 'event', '.clippy', func(){} )`, it definitely works but what if I only need the selector like this `$('.clippy')`, in order to test the selector I tried `$('.clippy').click(function(){ alert(1)})` but it does not work

I only need the selector because of integrating it on a plugin, plugin only needs selector like so `$('.clippy')`

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '{{ url('multiple-show-links') }}',
            data: { ids: val },
            success: function( i ) {
                $('#holder').html('');

                var html = '', datos = [], ctr = 0;
                $.each( i, function ( x ) {
                    html += '<div class="uploaded-file-popup-holder">' +
                                '<div class="uploaded-file-name">' +
                                    i[x].main_title +
                                '</div>' +
                            '<div class="uploaded-file-info-hoder">' +
                            '<table class="table table-bordered showlinks">' +

                            '<tr>' +
                                '<td class="col-red" width="168">Download Link:</td>' +
                                '<td class="b_1" id="link_download_' + ctr +'">' + i[x].url_download + '</td>' +
                                '<td id="copy_download" class="align-center valign-middle"><span id="c_1" class="clippy" data-text="' + i[x].url_download + '" data-clipboard-target="link_download_' + ctr +'">COPY</span></td>' +
                            '</tr>' +

                            '</table></div></div>';
                    ctr++;        
                });

                $('#holder').html(html);
            }

        });
```

Comment: I'd guess that the selector is not really the problem here. Both variants are valid and make sense. Could it be that you are trying to react on an event on an element that is dynamically loaded? In that case your issue is whether to use the `on()` or the `click()` function. For debugging your issue it probably makes sense to use your browsers debugging console to log what the two selectors actually select.

Comment: plugins don't care what selector you use...will still return DOM element collection. Initialize plugin after you insert the html

Comment: @charlietfl That can get pretty complicated when dealing with multiple dynamic elements on a page. Setting the event handler to the body tag is good option.

Comment: @feeela my assumption is that OP is trying to intialize a preexisting plugin. If plugin requires any element manipulation or doesn't support event delegation it's the only way ..and isn't that complicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is when you set the event handler.

In the second you set the event handler to a selector that does not exist in the moment. Thus no event handler is set.

```
$('.clippy').click(function(){ alert(1)})
```

In the first case you are using a global event handler attached to the already existing `body` element.

```
$('body').on( 'event', '.clippy', func(){} )
```

The event handler exists and will stay there. If the user clicks, the event handler does not fire because there was a click on `.clippy`, but because there was a click on the `body` element. But jQuery will only execute the callback, if the selector specified as second argument matches.

This is the usual way to use event handler in websites that add HTML dynamically to the page (e.g. after an AJAX call).